# css vertical-align:middle, line-height different than height

Tags: css

```
`.history-bar{
padding-left:10px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
height:35px;
line-height:16px;
width:472px;
vertical-align:middle;
color:black; 
}`
```

I read that line-height should be the same height of a div, to vertical-align:middle;
This div has 35px height but 16px line-height.
Is there any way to middle align this div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;` to vertical align the text.

```
.history-bar {
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    height:35px;
    line-height:16px;
    width:472px;
    color:black; 
    background: #eee;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/2d9We/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `vertical-align` property from your CSS, and yes, you can change the `line-height` to be the same as the `height`, like so:

```
.history-bar {
  padding-left:10px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height:35px;
  line-height:35px;
  width:472px;
  color:black; 
  border: 1px solid; /* added so you can see it's position */
}
```

[Here's a JSfiddle of the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/PTNmL/).

If you didn't set an explicit `height`, then you could manage the text's position via `padding` in the parent container, as well as margins (say if you used a `<p>` that had `margin-bottom` applied).

Comment: I just want to vertical-align:middle and have the height:35px; but the line-height:16px;